# Why does $\frac{z+2}{z-1}$ not have a series expansion around $|z-1|>1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Determine the Laurent series of $$z \mapsto \frac{z+2}{z-1}$$ over the region $$C := \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z-1| > 1 \right\} $$

---

With the region being simplified to

$$ \frac{1}{|z-1|} < 1$$

the solution would be

$$ 1+\frac{3}{z-1} $$

However, I am confused as to how this is the conclusion. Why is there no expansion of further terms of the Laurent series? Because if you change the inequality you get a actual expansion like so:

> In the annulus:
> $$C:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0<|z|<1 \} \\$$
> $$|z| < 1$$
> Gives:
> $$f(z)=\frac{z+2}{z-1}=1-3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$$

So why does that give a series solution but the first way does not?

Comment: The first way does give a series solution, it's just all but two of the coefficients are zero. A simpler example is $1/(1-z)$, which is already expressed as a Laurent series around $z=1$ (with only one term!) but is $1+z+z^2+\cdots$ around $z=0$. This even happens in the polynomial world: the Taylor series of $f(z)=z$ around $z=0$ is just the single term $z$, but around $z=1$ is $1+(z-1)$ which has two terms.

Comment: $\frac{z-2}{z+1}=1-\frac{3}{z+1}={1}{(z+1)^0} + \frac{-3}{(z+1)^1}$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_{n}}{(z+1)^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(z+1)^n$ where $b_{1} =-3,b_{n}=0 $ $\forall n\gt 1$ and $a_{1}=1,a_{n}=0 $ $\forall n \gt 1$ and radius of convergence  $0 < |z+1| < \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the first series you got is infact the Laurent series of $f(z)$ about z=1 and the second the Taylor series about z=0. What you've shown is that generally they don't agree.

> Page-442:Laurent's theorem: If $f(z)$ is analytic at an annlus centered at $a$, then $f(z)$ can be expressed as a Laurent series centered at $a$.
>
> Remark of theorem on page-443: If there are no singularities in $D$, then the inner edge of the annulus maybe completly collapsed, thereby transforming the annulus into a disc In this case, the laurent series does not contain negative powers, and, we recover Taylor series as a special case of Laurent series (paraphrased, not same as original)
>
> Picture:
>
> [image]
>
> Source: Visual Complex Analysis

Comment: One more point, in the picture Needham has a singularity marked by 2, you don't have any singularity except 1, so your outer radius is infinity. The inner radius could be thought of as limit going to zero since the expansion point is literally sitting on the singularity if that makes sense

Comment: With the limit to zero, i assume thats just whatever the singularity is. So if there's a singularity at I it'd be the limit to i

Comment: Yes you're right @user3655510